# I am having trouble getting my function to return a global varriable

Tags: python, django, function, if-statement

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Documents\lab3.py", line 18, in 
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Documents\lab3.py", line 15, in main
    finddiscount(quantity)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Documents\lab3.py", line 2, in finddiscount
    if quantity >= 1 and quantity <= 9:
NameError: global name 'quantity' is not defined

```
def finddiscount(discount):
    if quantity >= 1 and quantity <= 9:
        discount = "0%"
    elif quantity >= 10 and quantity <= 19:
        discount = "20%"
    elif quantity >= 20 and quantity <= 49:
        discount = "30%"
    elif quantity >= 50 and quantity <= 99:
        discount = "40%"
    elif quantity >= 100:
        discount = "50%"
    print (discount)    
def main():
    quantity = int(input("How many packages where purchased?"))
    finddiscount(quantity)
    price = float(input("How much is each item?"))
    return
main()
```

Comment: `quantity` is in `main`'s scope, not in the global scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
def finddiscount(quantity):   # not discount!
```